# Git show only author from commit hash?

Tags: git

I can't seem to figure out how to print out only the author from a commit hash using git.  This is what I have tried (and been trying to manipulate to get what I want).  How can I make it so that it only prints out the author, as specified with the '%n'?

```
git show --pretty="format:<author>%an</author>"  --name-only cf81c4a41517bdc5514d381c5309b80f5f4ca226
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want something like:

```
git show -s --pretty=%an cf81c4a41517bdc5514d381c5309b80f5f4ca226
```

From `git help show`:

> ```
>    -s, --no-patch
>        Suppress diff output. Useful for commands like git show that show the
>        patch by default, or to cancel the effect of --patch.
> ```